# A singly linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, linked-list

How is this Implementation of a list in C?

Please tell me whether it is good or please mention any problems.
It is a singly linked List and I tried to do it recursively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

void add(struct node *lst, int num){
    if(lst->next == NULL){
        lst->value = num;
        lst->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
        lst->next->next = NULL;
    }else{
        add(lst->next, num);
    }
}

void print_lst(struct node *lst){
    if(lst->next == NULL){

    }else{
        printf("\n%d", lst->value);
        print_lst(lst->next);
    }
}

int length(struct node *lst){
    if(lst->next == NULL){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1 + length(lst->next);
    }
}

int get(struct node *lst, int pos){
    if(pos < 0 ||  pos >= length(lst)){
        fprintf(stderr ,"\nIndexOutOfBoundsException\n");
    }else if(pos > 0 && pos <length(lst)){
        pos += -1;
        get(lst->next, pos);
    } else if (pos == 0){
        return  lst->value;
    }
}

int main ( ) {

    struct node lst;
    lst.next = NULL;
    add(&lst, 13);
    add(&lst, 12);
    add(&lst,  1);
    add(&lst, 10);
    add(&lst, 10);
    add(&lst, 4);
    //print_lst(&lst);
    printf("\n%d", get(&lst, 2));
    printf("\n%d", get(&lst, 5));
    printf("\n%d", get(&lst, 13));

    printf("\n\n%d", length(&lst));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Do not cast the result of `malloc`. If your code does `#include <stdlib.h>`, the cast is redundant. If it does not, the cast just masks the warning, which may lead to hard to find bugs.
- Prefer `sizeof(object)` to `sizeof(type)`. The latter leads to the double maintenance problem, in case the type is changed.
- I strongly recommend to have a constructor-like function to create a node:

  ```
  struct node * create_node(int num)
  {
      struct node * node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
      node->value = num;
      node->next = NULL;
      return node;
  }
  ```

  It will spare you plenty of trouble when the definition of `struct node` changes.
- You should get a warning that `get` doesn't always return a value (if you do not, enable all warnings, or change the compiler). It is a very serious warning, and in real life the code with such a problem leads to some dire consequences. You **must** `return get(lst->next, pos);` in a recursive clause.

  The fact that your `main` printed expected values is an unlucky coincidence.

  What to return in the `IndexOutOfBound` situation is a different matter. Consider returning an error code along with the value.
- Calling `length(lst)` at each level of recursion degrades performance to quadratic.
- As a side note, rather than testing for `position < 0`, consider passing a position as some unsigned type. `size_t` is the most obvious candidate.
- Along the same line, a low level utility function such as `get` should refrain from printing anything.
- I strongly advise agains recursion when an iterative solution is immediately available.

Comment: Thanks for the statement. Now I can improve my List. Thanks